# Is it possible to find a globally (or locally) optimal solution of $(P_0)$ with polynomial complexity? Much appreciated.

Tags: convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, integer-programming

I've got the following problem $(P_0)$:

$$(P_0)\qquad\min_{\mathbf{x}}f(\mathbf{x})\\
\qquad s.t.  x_n\in\{0,1\}\\
\qquad \mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}\le \mathbf{b},$$ where $f(\mathbf{x})$ is convex and differentiable, $\bf A$ is a totally unimodular matrix, vector $\mathbf{b}$ only contains $0$ or $1$, $\mathbf{x}=(x_n)_{n\in\mathcal{N}}$, and $\mathcal{N}=\{1,2,\cdots,N\}$. The task is to find a globally or locally solution with polynomial complexity.

I solve it like this.

First, by relaxing the binary constraint of $(P_0)$ as $x_n \in [0,1]$, I get $(P_1)$
$$(P_1)\qquad\min_{\mathbf{x}}f(\mathbf{x})\\
\qquad s.t.  x_n\in[0,1]\\
\qquad \mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}\le \mathbf{b},$$Now $(P_1)$ is a convex problem.

Then, by using CVX, I get a globally solution $\mathbf{x}^*$ of $(P_1)$. By projecting $\mathbf{x}^*$ onto the constraint set of $(P_0)$, I can obtain a feasible solution of $(P_0)$. However, $\mathbf{x}^*$ may not be the globally or locally optimal solution or even a stationary point of $(P_0)$.

So, my question is:

Is it possible to find a globally (or locally) optimal solution of $(P_0)$ with polynomial complexity? Much appreciated.

Comment: In general the answer is no. The correct transformation from $(P_0)$ to $(P_1)$ you performed is the common technique exactly because obtaining even a local optimal solution to $(P_0)$ is not possible in efficient time. Notice that when relaxing the original problem, it's possible to get a bound on the solution, i.e. how "far" it is from a solution to the original problem

Comment: Does $f$ have special structure?  For example, is it submodular?